# Get element attributes within inline styles

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html block:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="class" style="left:100px; top:0px">
 <div class="class" style="left:200px; top:0px">
 <div class="class" style="left:200px; top:100px">
</div>
```

I need to get the position of each from the inline css, how can I do that?

I know I can't use `.attr()` or js `getAttribute` as this would return the whole style block.

I ideally I'd like something like:

```
$(".container> .class").each(function(){
  var context = $(this);
  var thisLeft = context.left; // which I know is incorrect
}
```

Is this possible? JQuery or vanilla fine

Comment: `$('...').css('left')`. See http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In jQuery, you would do `$(this).css('left')`

```
$(".container> .class").each(function(){
    var thisLeft = $(this).css('left');
});
```

As @Fred said, usage of `this.style.left` doesn't care for the styles applied to the elements using style blocks or external css files, so just use `$.fn.css` method.

Comment: Be careful, the `style` property only considers inline styles. It won't take into account the styles applied through external stylesheets, for instance.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi isn't that **exactly** what OP is asking for?

Comment: @Phil, that's not how I read it. Questioner says *I need to get the position of each [element]*, but that position does not only depend on inline styles. Granted, the premise of the question may be flawed in the first place.

Comment: Thanks @FrédéricHamidi. Didn't know that. For that, I suppose `getComputedStyle` has to be used?

Comment: @Amit, on browsers that support it, yes (which means not IE8 and lower).

Answer (score 2):

Anoter solution is to use jquery `map` and get the value of all like:

```js
var pos = $(".container > .class").map(function() {
  return {
    left: $(this).css("left"),
    top: $(this).css("top"),
    right: $(this).css("top"),
    bottom: $(this).css("bottom"),
  }
}).get();

console.log(pos);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="class" style="left:100px; top:0px"></div>
  <div class="class" style="left:200px; top:0px"></div>
  <div class="class" style="left:200px; top:100px"></div>
</div>
```